# Delphi 10.4 Packages: "Add getit. getit contains implicit unit(s) %s."

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm trying to install packages in Delphi 10.4.

When I try to build one of the packages, i get the familiar warning dialog that Delphi needs to do *something*:

[image]

Normally we don't care about this dialog.

- We don't know what they mean.
- We don't care.
- They don't make sense.
- It's just one of those things that you click <kbd>OK</kbd> on so that Delphi shuts up and just does what we tell it to.

### Except in this case it's it's being a real pain

This time it says it needs to add `getit.`:

```
Add getit.
getit contains implicit unit(s) Exceptions.
```

And so i think, *"Whatever. I don't care what you need to work; just work."*. And it adds it to my package:

[image]

Of course, there's no way a code unit from 10 years ago is using **Getit** of 10.4. I didn't even have 10.4 until [Borland](https://www.ideracorp.com/developertools/embarcadero) forced it upon me a few days ago). But if Delphi says it needs to do something to the package: we let it.

Except what they did doesn't work.

[image]

So how do i **not** gain a dependency on `getit`. How do i stop Delphi from insisting that it needs getit anything?

Comment: Both of you and the GetIt developers chose to use the name Exceptions for a unit. If it comes to packages this is not going to work. So at least one of both (better both) has to change that unit name. I guess, you doing it can be achieved sooner.

In addition to that file a bug report, please.

Comment: It sucks that the internal **Exceptions.pas** is internal to getit.dcp, and yet the compiler is perfectly happy to find my unrelated unit.

Comment: As I said: It works perfectly for a standalone application, but barfs for a package loaded into the IDE. It is the old scheme: There can only be one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that **getit.dcp** uses an internal unit called `Exceptions`.

This unit isn't included anywhere with Delphi 10.4; it's just a secret unit internal to **getit.dcp**.

Which you think the compiler would continue to look inside **getit.dcp** for the **Exceptions** unit it needs.

Instead it seems happy to stumble across something completely unrelated that *happens* to have the same name.

- ideally the compiler would know to only look for things it needs in the location it knows it is
- and not pick up some chewing gum off the ground and start chewing it

So the solution is:

- change the name of my unit from `Exceptions.pas`
- to `Contoso.Exceptions.pas`

Comment: It wouldn't even help when the compiler ignored that. Actually you can tell it to do so by just clicking Cancel in the shown dialog. Only when you try to install that package in the IDE you will get a message that unit Exceptions is found in two packages, which is not allowed. Similar to a monolith Delphi application, one compiled with packages cannot contain a unit twice, even if these two units reside in different packages.

Comment: @UweRaabe I don't like it either. But at least we have the solution: change the name of my existing unit to avoid conflicts with internal hidden units that are are accessible by anyone.

Answer (score 3):

> We don't know what they mean

Then I suggest you learn, as this is really important stuff to understand about how packages work.

> there's no way a code unit from 10 years ago is using Getit of 10.4

True. But it likely does reference something that is not found in your project, but was found in the Getit package. Per https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/3646-delphi-1041-upgrade:

> When a unit is referenced by a package that is not contained in that package, it looks for other installed packages for this unit. **In this case it found one in the getit package.**
>
> That is standard behavior since ages. Try compiling a package that uses VCL.Controls without mentioning anything in the requires clause. Delphi will suggest to add vcl.

So, to avoid the IDE wanting to add the `getit` package, you need to add a reference to the correct package that contains the unit that the IDE is searching for (in this case, reference the package that has the `Exceptions` unit).

> Borland forced it upon me a few days ago

**Borland** has been out of the developer tool market since 2008, when they sold their tools to **Embarcadero**. And they didn't *force* you to upgrade, you *chose* to.

Comment: *"**Borland** has been out of the developer tool market since 2008"* I know, that's why i made the joke, and was sure to pre-emptively explain it to people who didn't get it. And, no, my choice would have been to continue to use 10.3; but they no expired my existing installation, and refuse to issue new keys. So 10.4 it is.

Comment: Either way, i think this is more of a comment rather than an answer *(only because it doesn't provide an answer to the problem)*